# Which C compilers do support #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON (or its equivalent)?

Tags: c, floating-point

Which C compilers do support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` (or its equivalent)?

cl (19.25.28611): does support via `#pragma fenv_access (on)`

gcc (10.2.0): no support: `warning: ignoring '#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS'` (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34678)

clang (11.0.0): no support: `warning: pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported` (it seems to be a patch: https://reviews.llvm.org/D69272)

icc: ??

Preferred target architecture: x86_64.

Comment: My (old) Intel compiler version 13.1.3.198 targeting `x86_64` supports it when configured for ISO-C99 (`/Qstd=c99`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C11:

- clang 12.0.0+
- icc 16.0.3+